# Computer emits long continuos beep on startup, but still boots

Tags: boot, bios

A computer starts up, but during boot it emits long high-pitched continuous sound; Meanwhile booting runs completely fine, and when Windows starts the sound stops and computer works fine.

I have checked this article: https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm and similar questions - I have supposed that problem is with memory. I have run a standard memory test, it did not show any errors.

I have started observing it after power failure.

**How to make computer start normally, without long beeping sound?**

BIOS version is `Hewlett-Packard 786E2 v02.04, 13.04.2007`

Comment: What brand of BIOS? The beep codes mean different things to different BIOS.

Comment: @spikey_richie : `Hewlett-Packard 786E2 v02.04, 13.04.2007`; also I have updated question

Comment: Does the power LED flash on and off as well?

Comment: like on normal startup (well, but sound beeps)